# Integrating IronPython in a Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, python, winforms, ironpython

I want to extend my Windows Forms Application programmed in C# with IronPython to enable the users of the software to extend the business logic with scripts. My Idea is to integrate a powerful editor with syntax highlighting and IntelliSense. At the moment I have no idea which editor I should use and how to access my Assemblies programmed in C# from the Python Script. Does anyone know, if there is
any Tutorial which covers this Issue or if there are any components available on the market, which I can integrate in my software to get the functionality I need.

Answer (score 3):

You dont have to do anything when calling your own assemblies from IronPython, it uses reflection to find types and members

For instance, I have a class OrderPrice

```
public class OrderPrice
{
  public decimal GetTotalPrice(Tariff.enumTariffType tariffType)
  {
    //....
  }
}
```

Then in C# I add the variable price to the ScriptScope

```
OrderPrice price = .....

ScriptScope scope = scriptEngine.CreateScope();
scope.SetVariable("price", price);
```

Then in the python script you just call the members needed

```
if price.ErrorText == None:
    totalType = price.GetTariffType()
    totalPrice = price.GetTotalPrice(totalType)
```

And if you want to instantiate C# objects from the script you must use the clr module and add dll's as reference

```
import clr

clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r"Entities.dll")

from Entities import OrderPrice

o = OrderPrice()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the informatin seems to be very helpful, I will try to play around with this Information tomorrow. Do you have any experience which Editor is the best to use in a Windows Forms Application to be able to create the Scripts with syntax highlighting and IntelliSense when the application is running.

Comment: Never coded Windows Forms in python, but I code python in notepad++

Comment: The Problem is,that I need some kind of editor, which I can integrate in my application. I will check, if this is possible with Notepad++.